# SQL Server : CASE-WHEN returns error in select list or Not-exist block if used in both

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the below SQL Server 2008 `select` statement `Case-When` is used in 2 places, in the select list and inside NOT EXISTS: CASE-1 and CASE-2.

It works only if I comment out one of case-when statements, only if I use it only in one place: select list OR not-exist.

If it used in both places, as below, I get error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I did my research, read http://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/sql/sqltip10.asp, but I still can not make it work.

Please help, what is wrong with code below? Thank you

- `MyTable.dob` is `nvarchar(10)`
- `PayrollTable.date_of_birth` is `varchar(10)`

Both dob columns are nullable.

- `MyTable.dob` is in format mmddyy like '010255'.
- `PayrollTable.date_of_birth` is in format 'mm/dd/yyyy' like '01/02/1955'

Code:

```
SELECT  
    FName,  
    LName,
    ( --- CASE-1
    select 
        CASE 
           WHEN CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(a.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')) > GETDATE()   
              THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(yy, -100, CAST(STUFF(STUFF(a.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE)), 101) 
              ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(STUFF(STUFF(a.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE), 101)
        END) as dob1
FROM
    MyTable a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         FName, LName, dob,
         -- StartDate source format = yyyymm  -  200104  ,  --- result = 2001-04-01 as DATE              
         MAX(CAST((STUFF(StartDate,5,0,'-') + '-01') AS DATE) ) as StartDate -- original format yyyymm                     
     FROM
         MyTable              
     WHERE
        -- mmddyy 
        CAST(SUBSTRING( dob, 5, 2) as INT) > 31  --yy               
        AND dob != '999999'               
     GROUP BY 
         FName, LName,  dob   --'mmddyy'                              
  ) as t ON   
   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.FName)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(t.FName))  AND  LTRIM(RTRIM(a.LName)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(t.LName)) 
   AND             
       a.dob = t.dob   --'mmddyy'          
   AND     
   CAST((STUFF(a.StartDate,5,0,'-') + '-01') AS DATE) = t.StartDate   

WHERE   ((LTRIM(RTRIM(a.FName)) != ''  and 
    a.FName is not null)           or 
    ( LTRIM(RTRIM(a.LName)) != ''  and a.LName is not null )     )  

and    

NOT EXISTS ----------------------------------
-- player does NOT exist in Party DIM alerady              
(
  select *
  from PayrollTable p  --- PARTY
  where                   
    p.date_of_birth = --t.dob  -- varchar(10) 1980-09-07  p.date_of_birth
    ( -- CASE-2
       select 
          CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')) > CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)        --t.dob
           THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(yy, -100, CAST(STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE)), 101) 
                       ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE), 101)     --t.dob
        END
    )                

        and 
    p.first_name = t.FName 
    and 
    p.last_name = t.LName        
)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what is in `MyTable.dob`  and `PayrollTable.date_of_birth`. Also are these fields nullable?

Comment: both dob fields are nullable, MyTable.dob is in format mmddyy like '010255'.  PayrollTable.date_of_birth is in format 'mm/dd/yyyy'  like '01/02/1955'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - Fix your data type issue and your conversion error will fix itself.

Comment: Where I do use wrong datatype?

Comment: Dates should be stored **as `DATE`** (or `DATETIME2(n)`) datatype - don't convert to string and then do extensive date manipulation on strings by concetenating and substringing - this is **madness!** Use the **most appropriate** datatypes - ***ALWAYS*** - no exception.

Comment: I can Not fix column datatype in db.

Comment: The likely answer to your question is that if for any particular set of conditions you don't get an error, this is luck, because the specific predicates used, and the internal execution path taken has avoided converting one of these invalid dates, but since you cannot guarantee the internal path, the only viable solution is to remove the invalid dates, and if you are doing this then you may as well take the extra step of using the proper data type. If you cannot do this then find the person that can, and tell them to do it.

Comment: It's an old db with 500K records.  I agree that it should be DATE type, but I can not change it now unfortunately ...

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here.

```
select *
from PayrollTable p  --- PARTY
where                   
p.date_of_birth = --t.dob  -- varchar(10) 1980-09-07  p.date_of_birth
( -- CASE-2
    select 
        CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')) > CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)        --t.dob
        THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(yy, -100, CAST(STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE)), 101)

        -- MISSING A WHEN CONDITION HERE

        THEN DATEADD(yy, -100, CAST(STUFF(STUFF('090780',3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE)) 
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(STUFF(STUFF(t.dob,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') AS DATE), 101)     --t.dob
    END
)
```

Comment: Sorry Jamie, it was My editing mistake, that line is commented OUT in original code. I have deleted it from my question now. I get error without that line.....

Comment: error text is in my question - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: well in your first case you reference a.dob and in your second you reference t.dob.  one apparently does not contain valid dates.

Comment: t.dob is subset of a.dob, adding    < and a.dob != '999999' >  to the where clause for table a  did not help.  AND If I comment out CASE-1   or CASE_2  - and leave the other - all works.  If I comment-out CASE-2 invalid a.dob should prevent query to work, right, but it works in this case.